# Unexpected behavior when computing the XOR between two signed 64-bit integers in python

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, xor

I need to compute the hamming distance between two integers by counting the number of differing bits between their binary representations.

This is the function that I am using for that purpose:

```
def hamming(a, b):
    # compute and return the Hamming distance between the integers
    return bin(int(a) ^ int(b)).count("1")
```

I started to conduct some simple tests on this function to make sure it works properly but almost immediately I see that it does not and I am trying to understand as to why.

I tested the function with these two numbers:

```
a = -1704441252336819740
b = -1704441252336819741
```

The binary representations of these numbers given by python are:

```
bin(a): -0b10111 10100111 01100100 01001001 11011010 00001110 11011110 00011100 
bin(b): -0b10111 10100111 01100100 01001001 11011010 00001110 11011110 00011101
```

As you can see their binary representations are the same aside for the first digit thus the hamming distance should be 1.
However, the returned hamming distance from the function is 3 and I can't seem to understand why.

The issue arises when I compute the XOR between these two digits as a ^ b returns 7 (thus counts 3 '1' bits) when I would expect it to return 1 (and count 1 '1' bit).

I believe this has to do with the fact that the XOR value seems to be getting stored as an unsigned integer with the minimal number of possible bits whereas I need it to be stored as a

How am I misunderstanding the XOR operator and how can I change my function to work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is the `bin` function that is misleading:
Instead of displaying the actual binary value stored, it displays |x| (absolute value) and prints minus sign in front of it for negative numbers.

But, that is not how the values are actually stored.

XOR operates on the actual binary values which are stored in [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), and that is why you are getting bigger bit difference then you expected.

As a simple example lets take two 4 bit numbers:

```
-10 = 0b0110
-11 = 0b0101
  ^ = 0b0011
```

As you can see, in this representation there are two bits of difference between these two numbers, while if they were positive, there would be only one bit difference.

Comment: Okay so my function works correctly; I just forgot how integers in 2's complement gets stored leading me to believe that my tests were failing which was further reinforced by the misleadingness of the bin function. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @LucaGuarro yes, `return bin(a ^ b).count("1")` will work correctly, as long as both `a` and `b` have the same sign. However, because of the way `bin` works, if one is positive and the other one negative, you will get the wrong result because XOR will produce a negative number which `bin` can't correctly translate.

Comment: hmm... I see, I should probably consider a different way of computing the hamming distance then

Comment: Since I can assume that I am always dealing with 64bit signed integers, I could normalize all my negative numbers to positive ones by applying `x = x + 2**64` to them, right? And then safely use my function as is since the numbers will all have the same sign

Comment: @LucaGuarro yes, that will work, but only under the assumption 64 bits is your fixed size. Python actually stores integers in an abject that can handle any size number, but if you are going to calculate bit difference between negative and positive numbers in 2's compliment, you must settle on a fixed length, to know how many 1's are in front of the negative number.